# Is there a way to see how much R computation is left from mac terminal?

Tags: r, for-loop, terminal, rstudio, computation

I have been running an R script that takes around 4 days to complete. The script involves a `for` loop that contains a text progress bar indicator, like so:

```
pb = txtProgressBar(min = 1, max = 60000, initial = 1, style = 3)

for(i in 1:60000){
print(i)
setTxtProgressBar(pb,ind)}
```

Last night, the Rstudio screen seems to have frozen at 82%, but I can see from the Activity Monitor application that the analysis is still running. Having committed ~3 days to computation, I'd rather not `ESC` and cancel the process to this point, just to restart and potentially have the same problem occur.

Is there a way to view how much time in the computation is left from the Mac terminal?